# Why can't I get data on same function in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This code is not working in view:

```
$data2 = array('sekiz'=>$this->Database_Model->hafalik_randevu('08:00', $tarih1, $tarih2));
$data2 = array('dokuz'=>$this->Database_Model->hafalik_randevu('09:00', $tarih1, $tarih2));
```

but this is work in view:

```
$data2 = array('sekiz'=>$this->Database_Model->hafalik_randevu('08:00', $tarih1, $tarih2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the previous set value.

**Make it:**

```
$data2['sekiz'] = $this->Database_Model->hafalik_randevu('08:00', $tarih1, $tarih2);
$data2['dokuz'] = $this->Database_Model->hafalik_randevu('09:00', $tarih1, $tarih2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `sekiz` is overridden by `dokuz`

Do it like this way :

```
$data2 = array(
            'sekiz'  => $this->Database_Model->hafalik_randevu('08:00', $tarih1, $tarih2),
            'dokuz'  => $this->Database_Model->hafalik_randevu('08:00', $tarih1, $tarih2)
        );
```

Your view :

```
$this->load->view('your_view',$data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use same variable names. If you use, the last variable value will be a output.

use like following.

```
$sekiz = $this->Database_Model->hafalik_randevu('08:00', $tarih1, $tarih2);
$dokuz = $this->Database_Model->hafalik_randevu('09:00', $tarih1, $tarih2);
$data2 = compact('sekiz','dokuz');   

$this->load->view('view_file',$data2);
```